# How do you add a Section Break to a google doc using the script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to write a script that will add a section break in a specific position on a google doc.

I've looked through the reference material and various functions, but cannot seem to find out how to do this. I did come across a Google Doc API reference for a java class called InsertSectionBreakRequest, but I can't make heads or tails of it honestly. Here's what I wrote, but the function isn't recognized:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Spreadsheet with the layout data
  var SourceId = "12DyHvTblahblahblahblahblahJ30g72bhLxKQ_NK0";
  var BlankDocId = "16NUdJblahblahblahblahblahdsPtWd11T826YJsxyk";

  // Open the spreadsheet and read everything in it
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SourceId).getSheetByName("Layout");
  var data = ss.getRange(1,1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());

  // Open the document so that it can be created
  var bdoc = DocumentApp.openById(BlankDocId);

  // First just set a variable for the active document
  bdoc.InsertSectionBreakRequest();
```

Now, I do understand that InsertSectionBreakRequest is a java class and that means it is probably an object that is instantiated in the gdoc itself and that this weak attempt at a function call by the same name is pretty bad, but I am kinda grasping straws here. Thanks for your patience.

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the problem:

- You want to use InsertSectionBreakRequest of the batchUpdate method in Google Docs API.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

### Modification points:

- InsertSectionBreakRequest is used for the batchUpdate method in Google Docs API. So in this case, [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). By this, InsertSectionBreakRequest can be used with the batchUpdate method.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the section break is added to the top of Document.

#### Sample script:

```
const documentId = "###";  // Please set the Document ID.

const resource = {requests: [{insertSectionBreak: {sectionType: "NEXT_PAGE", location: {index: 1}}}]};
Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
```

- In this case, `NEXT_PAGE` is used as `sectionType`. When `CONTINUOUS` is used, the section starts immediately after the last paragraph of the previous section. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#SectionType)

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the section break is added to the paragraph including `{{sectionbreak}}`. And the paragraph is removed after the section break was added. In this case, I thought that `add a section break in a specific position on a google doc` in your goal might be able to be achieved.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please copy and paste `{{sectionbreak}}` to the document body, and run it.

```
const documentId = "###";  // Please set the Document ID.

const doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
const body = doc.getBody();
const find = body.findText("{{sectionbreak}}");
if (find) {
  const child = find.getElement().getParent();
  const childIndex = body.getChildIndex(child);
  const docObj = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content;
  const resource = {requests: [
    {insertSectionBreak: {
      sectionType: "NEXT_PAGE",
      location: {index: docObj[childIndex + 1].startIndex}
    }}
  ]};
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
  find.getElement().removeFromParent();
}
```

### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, the method of `insertPageBreak` in Class Body of Document service is used. As the base script, the script of pattern 2 is used. In this case, the break is added to the paragraph including `{{sectionbreak}}`.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please copy and paste `{{sectionbreak}}` to the document body, and run it.

```
const documentId = "###";  // Please set the Document ID.

const doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
const body = doc.getBody();
const find = body.findText("{{sectionbreak}}");
if (find) {
  const child = find.getElement().getParent();
  const childIndex = body.getChildIndex(child);
  body.insertPageBreak(childIndex);
  find.getElement().removeFromParent();
}
```

### Note:

- Please run the script after Docs API was enabled at Advanced Google services.

### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [InsertSectionBreakRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertsectionbreakrequest)
- [SectionType](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#SectionType)
- [insertPageBreak(childIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertpagebreakchildindex)

Comment: I will try this.